# Data is not appending to Dropdown without page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

Hi everyone i am facing a weird problem, i am appending my drop downdata from jquery (fSlect Plugin) [Plugin link](https://github.com/mgibbs189/fSelect)

it is my select in html

```
<select name="ownerparm" class="demo" multiple="multiple" id="addownok">
</select>
```

and this is my function for appending data options

```
function Preload7()
{
    $("#addownok").find('option').remove();
    console.log("i am called preload7");
    $.getJSON("/FrontEnd/resources/getowner", function (jsonData) {
        $.each(jsonData, function (i, j) {

        $("#addownok").append($("<option value="+j.societyOwnerId+"></option>").html(j.socityOwnersNames));

        }); 
        $('#addownok').fSelect();
    });

}
```

without refresh of page whenever i try to call `Preload7()` function data is not appending to drop down, if i remove fSelect plugin then it will work fine(and if i Refresh page then it will append data with fSelect also) i want this without refreshing the page,

as you see when first time i load my application data is properly append in option and in fSelect DOM,
[image]

now when i add another owner it cannot append to fSelect DOm

[image]

as a result only 3 options is displayed in dropdown 
[image]

please tell me how to do this witout refreshing page i am waste my 3 days on it but i am not able to do it ?

Comment: Can we have a fiddle of the same ?

Comment: actually it is not able to show on fiddle, simple is that with fSelect plugin data is not appending, but when i refresh my page data is append with fSelect also

Comment: Did you try to reload it? `$('#addownok').fSelect().reload()`

Comment: yes i have tried this but it also not works ..

Comment: `$('#addownok').fSelect('reload');` should work, but i see its adding a duplicate search box. Alternate way could be `$('#addownok').fSelect('destroy').fSelect('create');`

Comment: @shakib, You are bang on target! Go on with this for answer...Here is the fiddle for you! https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/k425mtv1/20/

Comment: yes it works @shakib, thank you so much.....

Comment: thanks @RayonDabre , added as answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The plugin has some exposed API functions, such as `create`, `reload`, `destroy`

```
$('#addownok').fSelect('reload');
```

should reload the options after changes, but it also duplicates the search box,

Alternate solution,

```
$('#addownok').fSelect('destroy').fSelect('create');
```

hope this helps.

Comment: This is really helpful! As there is no proper documentation for this.. Do share if any!

Comment: I just skimmed through the https://github.com/mgibbs189/fSelect/blob/master/fSelect.js. Had a hunch seeing line 118 to 129 and it worked :). Sad there is no detail documentation.